# Decrypt with QT AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding

Tags: qt, mobile, aes, ecb

Hy,

I am developing an application for QT Mobile Symbian^3 devices. I need to decrypt a message encrypted using AES, ECB and PKCS5 padding.
Below is the java code that decrypts the message:

```
 public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {


        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    }
```

Do you know any solution for QT Symbian ?

Kind regards,
Bogdan

Answer (score 1):

Please check this: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/AES_Encryption-Rijndael_Block_Cipher_to_Symbian_OS. Maybe it helps.

Cheers,
Gaspar